# GAE Python - appengine_utilities doesn't save session variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I am trying to save a GET variable with the user for at least the session. My app is running on Google App Engine and I am using the Sessions module from appengine_utilities to save the variable, which is passed as a GET variable in the URL. When the variable is not included, the script falls back on a default value ("DEF").

Using the code below, if I call session["Source"] on the same page, everything works fine. As soon as I click to the next page, it forgets the initial variable and the script registers the default value. Any feedback would be very helpful!

```
    from appengine_utilities import sessions

    session = sessions.Session()
    if session.get('Source'):
      pass
    else:
      src = self.request.get('src')
      if src:
        session["Source"] = src
      else:
        session["Source"] = 'DEF'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to webapp2 sessions fixed the issue.
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html